# Trim Text to a Specific Limit of Characters with same Class

Tags: jquery, class, repeat

I cannot repeat the same class, otherwise I will get the text of all the elements shown.

I am doing the project with PHP and I can only give the same class, I have no choice.

I've tried a lot and I haven't found a solution.

The Read Less doesn't work for me either, but when I copied the code here it worked. I don't know what that is related to.

Can you help me use the class multiple times with the text of an element?

```js
$(function () {
    function trimText(selector, limit) {    
        var text = selector.text(),
            trim;

        selector.each(function() {
            if ($(this).text().length > limit) {
                trim = $(this).text().substr(0, limit);

                $(this).text(trim);
                $(this).append('<span class="expand">Read More<i class="fas fa-plus-circle">');
            };
        });

        $(selector).on("click",".expand", function() { //future element
            $(this).parent().text(text).append('<span class="collapse">Read Less<i class="fas fa-chevron-circle-up">');
        });

        $(selector).on("click", ".collapse",function() { //future element
            $(this).parent().text(trim).append('<span class="expand">Read More<i class="fas fa-plus-circle">');
        });

    };


    trimText($(".one"), 10);

})
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    align-self: start;
}

.text {
    margin: 20px auto;
    background-color: #ccc;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #bbb;
    border-radius: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 18px;
    width: 40%;
    line-height: 1.5;
}

.text span.expand,
.text span.collapse {
    margin: 10px;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    color: #9a031e;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block
}

.text span.collapse {
    color: #00a896;
}

.text span.expand   .fa-plus-circle,
.text span.collapse .fa-chevron-circle-up {
    margin-left: 8px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Trim Text</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="text one">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</div>
    <div class="text one">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to move everything into your `each` loop, otherwise you're setting the same text for every `.one` element.

Comment: @user7290573 Can you create an example please?